# If I have a set of related rows in one table, how can I decorate them with the index in the group?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables `score` and `game`. Each game has `n` scores. I'd like to get `n` for each score of the games. So I'll get:

```
round, score, game
==================
1      1      1
2      2      1
3      3      1
1      9      2
2      3      2
```

Example fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56434/1

Comment: you want to get Count of score for each game ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  RoundNo, Score, ID
FROM
        (
            select  a.ID,
                    b.Score,
                    @sum := if(@nme = a.ID, @sum ,0) + 1 RoundNo,
                    @nme := a.ID
            from    game a
                    INNER JOIN scores b
                      ON a.ID = b.game_ID
                    CROSS JOIN
                    (select @nme := '', @sum := 0) vars
            order   by  a.ID
        ) s
ORDER   BY ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56434/18)

OUTPUT

```
╔═════════╦═══════╦════╗
║ ROUNDNO ║ SCORE ║ ID ║
╠═════════╬═══════╬════╣
║       1 ║    14 ║  1 ║
║       2 ║    10 ║  1 ║
║       1 ║    19 ║  2 ║
║       2 ║    20 ║  2 ║
║       3 ║    25 ║  2 ║
╚═════════╩═══════╩════╝
```